# To change the color of the spinner text font

Tags: xamarin.android, android-spinner, textcolor

I saw this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/spinner

I want to change color of the spinner text font:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:textColor="#FF0080FF"
    android:popupBackground="#FF553232"
    android:background="#FFD733D7"/>
```

But in the output, Color of text is always white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1. add your custom theme to style.xml. This will change the textcolor of items in the dropdown list.
[image]

```
<style name="MySpinnerTheme" parent="android:Theme">
   <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
</style>
```

layout

```
<Spinner
   android:id="@+id/spinner1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/MySpinnerTheme"
   android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
```

Option 2. If you want to change the selected item only.
[image]

```
...

Spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(spinner_ItemSelected);

...

private void spinner_ItemSelected(object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e){
   Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;
   TextView textView = (TextView)spinner.SelectedView;
   
   textView.SetTextColor(Color.Rgb(0, 235, 0));
}
```